# Strange error seemingly related to embeds(discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am implementing a mute command to my bot and it is supposed to post an embed(taken from a dictionary) as a way of logging the action. Unfortunately, it keeps giving this error:

```
await channel.send(embed = Embed().from_dict(log_embed(target = target, mod = ctx.author, action = 'muted', reason = reason)))

TypeError: Object of type Member is not JSON serializable
```

Any idea what is wrong or how to fix it?
Code:

```
def log_embed(target : discord.User, mod : discord.User, action : str, reason : str = None):
  embed = {
    'title' : target.mention + ' has been ' + action,
    'type' : 'rich',
    'color' : color,
    'fields' : [
      {
        'name' : 'Name:',
        'value' : target
      },
      {
        'name' : 'Moderator:',
        'value' : mod
      },
      {
        'name' : 'Reason:',
        'inline' : True
      }
    ]
  }
  if reason:
    embed['fields'][2]['value'] = reason.capitalize()
  else:
    embed['fields'][2]['value'] = 'No reason given'
  return embed

@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Staff')
async def mute(ctx, target : discord.User = None, reason : str = None):
  if target:
    await target.add_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='muted'))
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='mod-log')
    await channel.send(embed = Embed().from_dict(log_embed(target = target, mod = ctx.author, action = 'muted', reason = reason)))
```

Comment: Full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `Embed().from_dict()`.

In your case you can simply unpack the dictionary that you get from the `log_embed` function.

```py
await channel.send(embed = Embed(**log_embed(target = target, mod = ctx.author, action = 'muted', reason = reason)))
```

And you would also need to .mention the users to get mention strings.
In the beginning of the `log_embed` function add this:

```py
mod = mod.mention
target = target.mention
```

Comment: So... it almost works, except only the title of the embed shows up(without the fields) any ideas?

Comment: @CheeseDeleter have you added the second piece of code to your log_embed function?

Comment: i have, but it does this weird thing where it just shows up like this - <@!653555778887745537> has been muted

Answer (score 0):

[`from_dict`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=from_dict#discord.Embed.from_dict) is a classmethod, so you shouldn't be calling it from an instance. Simply do `Embed.from_dict(args...)`.

Also note that you need `target: discord.Member` if you want to add roles to it, and your `color` in `log_embed` is not defined.

---

The problem arises from the fact that you put the `target` and `mod` objects *directly* into the embed dictionary. You did

```py
'value': target
# ...
'value': mod
```

which puts *the actual user object* into that dictionary. That is not serializable as the error says. Instead, you need to put it in as a string in some way:

```py
'value': str(target)  # "username#1234"
'value': f'{target.display_name}'  # "usernameornickname"
'value': f'{target.mention}'  # "<@username>"
```